# How to force a neural network to have Gaussian hidden activations

Tags: classification, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

Let the task be classification and the neural network under discussion to have Sigmoid activation functions and be trained by Backpropagation and SGD. How can I force the networks hidden activations to be normally distributed for each class while using gradient descent?

The idea is to simplify statistical analysis with only slight degradation of performance.

Comment: `to be normally distributed for each class` - I don't understand this. The hidden units compute an activation for _every_ class in the output because they are fully connected. Why would you want to control the hidden unit activation values anyways? And pretty sure you can just change the sigmoid activation function to a [gaussian one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function)

Comment: I want the activations (after a hidden layer) of the samples for a given class to be normally distributed. The reason is to simplify statistical analysis, e.g. the optimal separator between two normal distributions is known. A Gaussian activation function does not necessarily create Gaussian distributed activation values.

Comment: I believe you are looking for *batch normalization*: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf

Comment: @tlg, how does batch normalization cause the activations to become gaussian?!

Comment: Batch normalization normalizes some moments of samples. This does not enforce Gaussian activations: https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2000.10474556#.W5jLv84zZpg

Comment: Question is not unclear. I added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "force" it, but you can surely add terms to your loss function that would make your network try to minimize the dissimilarity between the distribution of said activations and a probability distribution.

Namely, you can employ the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) to this end, adding specific terms to your loss function.

This is done in Variational Autoencoders (VAEs), for example.